# How I can combine np.where and fillna for pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**Data:**

```
Col1       Result 

 good       positive 
 bad        NaN
 excellent  NaN
 good       NaN        
 good       NaN
```

**Required output:**

```
 Col1       Result 

 good       positive 
 bad        positive
 excellent  NaN
 good       negative        
 good       negative
```

I have following two condition and want to integrate it with `.fillna`, these condition apply only for NaN values in the `result` column

```
df['result'] = np.where(df['col1'] == 'good',  'negative',df['result'])
df['result'] = np.where(df['col1'] == 'bad',   'positive',df['result'])
```

Comment: Can you add some small data sample, e.g. 5 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need replace missing values by col1 column add [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['Result'] = np.where(df['Col1'] == 'good',df['Result'].fillna('negative'),df['Result'])
df['Result'] = np.where(df['Col1'] == 'bad',df['Result'].fillna('positive'),df['Result'])
```

In my opinion better here is use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['Result'] = df['Result'].fillna(df['Col1'].map({'good':'negative','bad':'positive'}))
print (df)
        Col1    Result
0       good  positive
1        bad  positive
2  excellent       NaN
3       good  negative
4       good  negative
```